# Using QGIS Webmap with Mapbox

Tags: qgis, mapbox, contour, transparency-opacity

Im trying to produce a contour map using QGIS and exporting using Mapbox. The map is rotated 90 degrees in QGIS and it returns to its normal orientation if I use Leaflet. Unfortunately, using the Mapbox output, the transparent parts of the layer come out black.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this?

[image]